# Connect MacBook Pro Unibody to Apple Cinema Display

Tags: cable, mini-displayport

I have a 15" unibody MacBook Pro with a [Mini DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort) and a 23" Apple Cinema HD Display with the [Apple Display Connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Display_Connector). I've been trying to find an adapter to connect the two but haven't been able to find one. Is there a cable available to make this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Your most cost effective solution would be to get an [ADC to DVI adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000067RLH) and then a [DVI to Mini DisplayPort adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/A?fnode=MTY1NDA3Ng&mco=MTA4NDU0ODY)

While it does mean you're going through multiple cables, but I couldn't find anyone who still makes a ADC - Mini Display Port adapter, and it does give you a handy adapter for if you buy a more modern, non-apple, display.

Comment: Hmm.. That won't work actually. I've found the solution for it though. (It's expensive!). I'll have to get a DVI to ADC Display Adapter (currently unavailable on Amazon http://www.amazon.com/Apple-M8661LL-Display-Adapter-4038234011420/dp/B00011KHT2). Then connect the DVI cable to the DVI to Mini DisplayPort adapter.

Comment: I linked to a DVI - ADC adapter that was in stock O.o

Comment: the cable you linked to is for output *from* a Mac with ADC, not input *to* a display with ADC. Read the product description; sadly, it's not bi-directional.